# It's possible to consume AWS S3 stored emails via Server Sent Events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, email-client

I'm receiving emails using AWS SES and storing on S3 bucket.

I order to put each email in the hands of users,  I'm looking for the best way to poll a service and download emails.

Knowing that S3 is just a storage,  not an IMAP/POP server,  it's clear that an email client cannot be "connected".

I also know AWS offers WorkMail a ready to use IMAP service.  I'm working for a government agency with more than 5 thousand users and there is no way to pay USD $2, $3 per user,  not even a penny per user.  So I have to figure how to poll and download emails to users from an AWS S3 bucket, providing an experience near similar to email client,  it can be a web app.

Actually the SES service is working well,  each mail is stored as expected in an S3 bucket.

Comment: You can forward the mail received to SES to different user accounts. If it works for you, check the following article https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/forwarding-emails-to-your-inbox-using-amazon-ses-2d261d60e417 You might need to modify the Lambda function to forward to different users.

Comment: @Ashan I think the medium article is a good answer to my question.  This is a good alternative,  the second less desirable but viable too is to deploy an instance an make it work as an IMAP server,  just for inbound email.  The perils of running ones own email server are more on the delivery side (SPF, DKIM, DMARC),  which AWS SES solves nicely.  So please make your comment an answer in order to award it,  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forward the mail received to SES to different user accounts. If it works for you, check the following article on [Forwarding Emails to your Inbox Using Amazon SES](https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/forwarding-emails-to-your-inbox-using-amazon-ses-2d261d60e417). You might need to modify the Lambda function to forward to different users.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a long comment than an answer as I don't think your stated goals have an good answer. No US government (city, state or federal) could legally  accept the solution that you are reviewing - budget or no budget.

Amazon S3 is not free. There is a storage cost per month plus the cost for data transfer.

You may think that you can just delete the emails on S3. How are you going to meet legal and accounting responsibility for email retainership and audit trail? One subpoena and all xxxx will break loose. Federal law for governments requires that certain emails become government records. How are you going to prove which emails were transitory, short-term or long-term?

Most emails today are HTML. Just downloading them and looking at the raw text will be useless. What email client are you going to use? Most that I know of do not support importing raw files as email.

How much is your burdened salary cost to the company? I can just begin to image all of the support issues that you or someone will face trying to manage this environment for 5,000 employees.

Most people use email today as a big database of information, contacts, calendars, etc.

Email is incredibly useful and when used properly a very powerful tool for businesses. I cannot image the lost productivity this organization will suffer in  trying to save two or three dollars a month. Not long ago a real company email address cost $25 or more per employee.

If my company had five thousand users, I would engage an email service company that provided an entire email server as a service. This would reduce the per email account costs.

And lastly, if my employer could not afford email for each employee my new resume would be my first task to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,  this is a non US government agency,  where laws are different and devoted to open source software.  More than lacking money is that money is yet assigned and is painful to move from one destination to another,  by painfully I mean,  criminal investigation,  so decision makers are usually afraid of moving a pen. Now we are running many servers on AWS and the bills will be payed because the budget was discussed, approved and erogated.